# Check if ParseQuery is loading

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

In my Fragment, the ParseQuery successfully queries as follows:

```
                comments = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("CommentItem");
                comments.setLimit(99);
                comments.whereEqualTo("parentUser", feedUserName);
                comments.whereEqualTo("parentFeed", feedItem);
                comments.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> mobjects, ParseException e) {

                        if(e == null){

                            for(ParseObject object : objects){




                            }


                        }


                    }
                });
```

However, if the connection is slow, only the background is visible until it queries. How can I show a loading symbol while the parse query is loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to show progress dialog before executing findInBackground and dismiss it inside the callback. 
so your code should look like the following:

```js
comments = new ParseQuery < ParseObject > ("CommentItem");
comments.setLimit(99);
comments.whereEqualTo("parentUser", feedUserName);
comments.whereEqualTo("parentFeed", feedItem);

// show progres dialog 
final ProgressDialog myDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading...","Loading Results...", true);

comments.findInBackground(new FindCallback < ParseObject > () {@
  Override
  public void done(List < ParseObject > mobjects, ParseException e) {

    myDialog.dismiss();  // remove progress dialog on finish
    if (e == null) {

      for (ParseObject object: objects) {




      }


    }


  }
});
```

Good Luck.